# Event not firing on input change for appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form, there's a button to add additional elements as needed by the user. For each input field, there's a .change() handler. The issue is that the .change does not fire on appended form elements but still triggers on existing form elements. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
$mainElement = $(this); // memorize $(this)
$sibling = $mainElement.next('input'); // find a sibling to $this.
$sibling.change(function($mainElement) {
    return function() {
        $mainElement.text('My textfield changed');
    }
}($mainElement));
```

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WCDBr/22

Comment: just to double check. What you want is that when you click on button "Add" you should see on the page whatever you typed in the input fields?

Comment: On the existing elements, when you type something in the input and mouse out, the label changes. On the elements inserted using the "Add" button, that doesnt happen.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't append any form elements.  But if you append elements, you'll need to set the change event on each element as it is appended.

Comment: Did you click on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/WCDBr/22/ ? There's and "Add" button as part of the page. When clicked, it adds another input field.

Comment: @Jim I think I have the solution for your question. Just double checking one more time. So you have 4 input fields (each of them with a label), so if you type something in the first input field and as soon as you go to the next input filed you want the "My textfield changed" message right above the first input field and so on?

Comment: For each input field, when something is typed, I want the label to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of simplicity i copy pasted the code.

On Clicking the "Add" button you not binding the change event again for the newly created element. Do This on Click:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
$('ul').append('<li><p class="element">Lorem ipsum</p><input/></li>');
$('.element').each(function() {
    $mainElement = $(this); // memorize $(this)
    $sibling = $mainElement.next('input'); // find a sibling to $this.
    $sibling.change(function($mainElement) {
        return function() {
            $mainElement.text('My textfield changed');
        }
    }($mainElement));
});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the on method:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {});
//or
$(document).on('change', '.inputclass', function() {});
```

It registers the event with the document and it should work even for newly added documents.  Your change event registered with existing elements.